# Determining type of modulation

Tags: rf, modulation, transmitter, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

The circuit below is a radio transmitter circuit of a typical RC car. The circuit makes use of IC [TX2](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FWW/CD13/GV525G0X/FWWCD13GV525G0X.pdf) encoder.

The output of IC ("SO" pin) is a series of pulses at low speed (84 Hz). This signal will be modulated by a crystal, onto an RF carrier (27 MHz) in order to be transmitted. Transmission is at 27 MHz.

Is it safe to assume that modulation is AM (as frequency remains the same)? Does circuit indicates the type of modulation? I know that part of the transmitter circuit is the modulator circuit, but I can't find which part is exactly.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Note "AM or FM" is a false dichotomy. There are many kinds of modulation that are neither, or both.

Comment: That is correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be [on-off keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying) which can be thought of as amplitude modulation where the modulating signal (SO) has just two levels, 0 (no carrier) and 1 (full carrier).

[image]
<sub>(source: [sitelec.org](http://sitelec.org/cours/abati/domo/images/codage2.gif))</sub>

Comment: If I understood, when SO output is high (base of the right transistor gets biased) it allows 27MHz signal to be transmitted, otherwise not. What is the purpose of the left transistor? It is part of the oscillator circuit? Osillator circuit except crystal, includes any other component?

Comment: The left transistor is part of the oscillator circuit (one must have gain to have an oscillator so an active device, e.g., a BJT, is required).  The right transistor ia a common-emitter amplifier, coupling the output of the oscillator to the antenna, that is either on or off according to the state of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an AM transmitter. When the SO output is high the rightmost transistor C1815 gets biased into conduction. When SO is low the transistor's base will be pulled low, and the transmitter will be off. It's called CW (continuous wave) transmission.

Note: I would place a coil in series with the 6k8 resistor, so that the SO output doesn't load the oscillator.

Comment: Both transistors are tagged C1815.